# Adding the median value to every box (not ggplot)

Tags: r, boxplot, axis-labels, r-raster

I have a boxplot from the code below and i want to add median values.

`boxplot(ndvi_pct_sep~edge_direction, data= data_sample, subset = edge_direction %in% c(64,4, 1,16),ylab="NDVI2028-2016", xlab="Forest edge direction",names=c("north", "south", "east", "west"))`

[image]

.
I want to add the median values to the boxplots, any idea how to do it?

Comment: Could you give us an example of your data using `dput()` or if it is very large `dput(head(df,5))`

Answer (score 1):

It will likely involve using legends - since I don't have your data I cant make it perfect, but the below code should get you started using the ToothGrowth data contained in R. I am showing a base R and ggplot example (I know you said no ggplot, but others may use it).

```
# Load libraries
library(dplyr); library(ggplot2)

# get median data
mediandata <- ToothGrowth %>% group_by(dose) %>% summarise(median = median(len, na.rm = TRUE))
l <- unname(unlist(mediandata))
tg <- ToothGrowth # for convenience 
tg$dose <- as.factor(tg$dose)

### Base R approach
boxplot(len ~ dose, data = tg,
        main = "Guinea Pigs' Tooth Growth",
        xlab = "Vitamin C dose mg",
        ylab = "tooth length", col = "red")
for (i in 1:3){
  legend(i-0.65,l[i+3]+5, legend = paste0("Median: ",l[i+3]), bty = "n")
}

### ggplot approach
ggplot(data = tg, aes(dose, len)) + 
  theme_classic() + theme(legend.position = "none") +
  geom_boxplot()+
  annotate("text",
           x = c(1,2,3),
           y = l[4:6]+1, # shit so you can read it
           label = l[4:6])
```

Base R:
[image: BaseR]

ggplot:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here's a straightforward solution with `text` and without `for`loop:

Toy data:

```
set.seed(12)
df <- data.frame(
  var1 = sample(LETTERS[1:4], 100, replace = TRUE),
  var2 = rnorm(100)
)
```

Calculate the medians:

```
library(dplyr)
med <- df %>%
  group_by(var1) %>%
  summarise(medians = median(var2)) %>%
  pull(medians)
```

Alternatively, in `base R`:

```
bx <- boxplot(df$var2 ~ df$var1)
med <- bx$stats[3,1:4]
```

Boxplot:

```
boxplot(df$var2 ~ df$var1)
```

Annotate boxplots:

```
text(1:4, med, round(med,3), pos = 3, cex = 0.6)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can do

```
b <- boxplot(count ~ spray, data = InsectSprays, col = "lightgray", boxwex=.2)
s <- b$stats
text(1:ncol(s)+.4, s[3,], round(s[3,],1), col="red")
```

[image]